# HTTP Post/get traffic interception - safari

Tags: macos, http, safari

I am developing a security software which needs to block emails with sensitive body & attachments  (CCN ,SSN.. etc) in Safari.

I've been successful in loading my Bundle into Safari Process & am trying to override NSURLConnection & other CFNetwork API which are used for HTTP GET/POST requests.
I am able to capture all the GET requests , but no luck with HTTP Post requests.

I've also tried writing a NPAPI plugin without any success.

I need to handle it at application level & not using any proxies.

Any pointers towards intercepting HTTP POST requets for Safari on MAC OS would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks for the help.